# How to display a nice Tree of Folders and Subfolders selected?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Alright, so I'm using webkit multiupload feature that chrome provides.Right now, The user can select a folder and all the files are listed in a textbox. Now, when he naviagtes to the next page, I want to create a nice display of the form

```
Folder
  1.File 1.php
  2.File 2.mp3
  Subfolder
     1.File 3.avi
     2.File 5.php
     Subfolder2
```

I'm currently using PHP form to send the data of the textbox containing the list of files of the form

Answer (score 0):

you could use http://www.jstree.com/.
This is an opensource javascript libarary witch enables you to show a treevieuw

```
<div id="html1">
  <ul>
    <li>Folder
      <ul>
        <li>1.File 1.php</li>
        <li>2.File 2.mp3</a></li>
        <li>Subfolder
            <ul>
            <li>1.File 3.avi</li>
            <li>2.File 5.php</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and as javascript

```
$('#html1').jstree();.
```

Comment: Thanks a nice library to work with. But converting this file list into list like the above might be a bit of a problem. Can you go over any algorithm that pattern matches and gives me the desired result?

Comment: what is the datastructure of the input from the folders?

Comment: The list of the form

/Movies/Files/
/Movies/Files/1.avi
/Movies/Files/2.avi
/Movies/Test/2.avi